# Packaging headers and pre-built libs into CMake package

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a multi-platforms pre-built C++ library. By multi-platforms, I mean a separated files for each platform. I do not have access to the code (and I won't).

The provider of the library did not provide a CMake support to include the library using CMake. Is it possible to package those file in a way that I can do this:

```
find_package(x REQUIRED)
```

to use this library in my CMake-based projects?

Comment: I write my own finders in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use find_package directly for those libraries that do not support cmake find. You need to have find module or write using find_library and find_path.

Please refer the examples here: [Adding compiled libraries and include files to a CMake Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601798/adding-compiled-libraries-and-include-files-to-a-cmake-project)